# How can I disable scrollbar by resizing elements?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Here is the image of my current page: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9TeT.png)

As you can see there's a scrollbar and I want to disable it but not by set overflow to hidden and something like that.

I want to disable it by resizing elements on the page.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/m2xk3td6/

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt Thanks a lot for your helping but it didn't fix it. You can see the difference in https://imgur.com/1ZDyFkp

Answer (score 0):

1. The code below can make your scrollbar `invisible` but still work:

```
.class-of-your-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

2.If you mean `disable the scroll behavior`,then you should make sure your document content's height won't exeed the window's height.It is hard because the users screen's height is not the same.To acheive this,you can add **height:100%** to your container element.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe it's because of using Vue and vuetify.

Comment: @Ali can you post a **jsfiddler link** of your example?

Comment: Can I share the folder of the project? Because I think this problem is related to multiple components.

Comment: Here is the folder of the project: https://ufile.io/689lzrv8 I'll be thankful if you would help me and fix this damn problem

Comment: i am sorry that i  can't build the project successful. I think your problem is just about CSS/Layout,you can make a simple demo html that focus on  this **scroll problem** in jsfiddle